# Speedometer for car

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, gps, speed

I want to build a speedometer for a car using Arduino UNO.
For the display, I'm using an LCD screen that will be located behind the steering wheel.
For context, I'm building the speedometer for a Tesla, which does not have a speedometer behind the steering wheel.
Because this speedometer is for a car, and for driving purposes, I need the speedometer to be very accurate.
I am planning to calculate the current speed of the car using a GPS module, but not sure **which GPS module would have the best accuracy but is not too expensive?**
I am also open to other methods that may be available to measure current speed.

Comment: An interesting project. I will not vote, but since there is no mention of an Arduino, likely people will vote to close this question as off topic. As for GPS, most inexpensive modules will only be accurate to about +/- 10 meters and only work (well) w/a clear view of the sky. Some will calculate bearing and speed for you (i.e. likely all you have to do is pluck this data out of the stream of data coming out of the GPS). Before investing time building this, consider using an old Android phone & an application which reports the data of interest to you.

Comment: For me, it would make more sense to read the speed from CAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a GPS speedometer for an old Corvette using the TinyGPSPlus library with a GY-NEO6MV2 NEO-6M with an Arduino Uno.
http://www.carols62.com/speedo
Speed readings were very accurate.

Comment: hey thanks, this seems like exactly what I need!